# Detect the ID of a clicked link to change where the link goes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make a JavaScript function called `testBrowser()` that detects if the user is on a mobile device (I have this working).

I have three links that run the same function, but I want each one to have a different outcome. I've figured out the way I'd like to do it, but can't actually do it as I need to detect the ID of the link clicked. None of the options I find online seem to work!

I'm struggling to explain this, but reading my code should help.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:testBrowser()" id="tumblr">z</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:testBrowser()" id="twitter">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:testBrowser()" id="insta">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function testBrowser(){
    if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod/BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
        if($(this).attr('id') = "insta"){
            window.location = "instagram://user?id=xxxxxxxx";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') = "tumblr"){
            window.location = "tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=blogname";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') = "twitter"){
            window.location = "twitter://user?screen_name=handle";
        }
    }
    else{
        if($(this).attr('id') = "insta"){
            window.location = "http://www.instagram.com/id";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') = "tumblr"){
            window.location = "http://blogname.tumblr.com/";
        }
        else if($(this).attr('id') = "twitter"){
            window.location = "http://www.twitter.com/handle";
        }           
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/th3no0b/yhar3grv/1/)

Comment: invoking from the `href` isn't going to return the correct this. You need to programmatically add click functions to the links.

Comment: Are you looking at the console to catch errors? There are a couple that you should work through. You can also use the JS console to output things like `console.log(this)` to see that it's not the correct `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking from the `href` this way isn't going to return the correct `this` reference (it will reference the `window` and not the `anchor`). You can programmatically add click functions to the links. *jQuery* can do this in just one line. This is actually the preferred way.

```
$("li > a[id]").on("click", testBrowser);
```

This will select the anchors and add `testBrowser` as function.

Other improvements:

- You used single `=` in your if clauses, they need to be double `==` or triple `===` to compare.
- Your regex contained an error where an `/` needed to be a `|`.
- I changed the `hrefs` to `void(0)`, so they still act as link, but effectively do nothing.

```js
$("li > a[id]").on("click", testBrowser);


function testBrowser(){
            if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
                if($(this).attr('id') == "insta"){
                    window.location = "instagram://user?id=xxxxxxxx";
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id') == "tumblr"){
                    window.location = "tumblr://x-callback-url/blog?blogName=blogname";
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id') == "twitter"){
                    window.location = "twitter://user?screen_name=handle";
                }
            }
            else{
                if($(this).attr('id') == "insta"){
                    window.location = "http://www.instagram.com/id";
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id') == "tumblr"){
                    window.location = "http://blogname.tumblr.com/";
                }
                else if($(this).attr('id') == "twitter"){
                    window.location = "http://www.twitter.com/handle";
                }

            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tumblr">z</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="twitter">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="insta">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks so much! Just one thing: is it possible to have the link as `target="_blank"` still?

Comment: @Th3No0b, no, but you can use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) instead of `window.location`. Opens the url in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

The current way of calling `testBrowser` executes it in the global object context, e.i. `window`. You can change HTML like this:

```
<a href="javascript:testBrowser.call(this)" target="_blank" class="socicon" id="tumblr">z</a>
```

**UPD.** Abobe will not work. It should be `onclick="testBrowser.call(this)"` attribute, with `href="javascript:` context itself is global object, so call(this) makes no sense. jQuery solution is much better.

In this case you can just use `this.id` to access link `id`. No need to wrap it with `$()`.

Problem #2. Use comparison operator `===` not assignment `=`:

```
if (this.id === "insta") {
    window.location = "instagram://user?id=xxxxxxxx";
}
```

Comment: @Th3No0b Are you using your console to debug your code. Because your original code has issues. dfsq's suggestions should work normally. As I mentioned, there is a syntax error in your regex. If you do not know how to bring up the console: use keyboard `F12`, to bring it up. It will show you script errors.

Comment: Yeah I am, I don't see any errors that way. That regex error isn't in my actual code, I think it was a typo when I copied the code over somehow. You're solution below works fine though! Thanks!